# Reduce Overheating of an old Audio Video Receiver - Harman/Kardon 3500

Tags: heat, overheat

Because good AVRs are super expensive, I got one cheaply from a friend. It works really decently, but recently it started to turn itself off after a while. With my technical background I looked into it, but I am not that deep into audio-tech.

The only thing I felt so far is that this thing gets incredibly hot. I know AVRs do get way hotter than laptops because they have no active cooling (fans) only passive grills, but it is so hot that I could make toast on it.

Are there any good ideas what I should do and check if I open it up? I am not really scared to open and measure a bit around, but not knowing what to measure and where to look is the main problem. Any tips would help.

The AVR stays on the shelf, pretty open with good air around it so I doubt it's that.

My Soundsystem is a Teufel Consono 35 Mk3 which should be fine

Manual of the AVR doesn't say anything helpful as well:
https://servlib.com/harman-kardon/audio/avr-3500-sm2.html

Thanks!

Comment: That link to the manual in German is not going to be useful to a large fraction of the folks on this platform. Can you try to find a manual in English since you are asking your question in English?

Comment: My bad! did paste the wrong link. Changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize crossover distortion and variations of NPN+PNP Vbe drops, they use a pot.

Locate the Test points and measure with a voltmeter.
This represents the current through a 0.33 OHm resistor and also the transistors.

It may indicate a **fault or just too high a setting.**

I found the service manual online.

[image]